# Convert int 60 to a time value of 60 minutes

Tags: php, datetime, casting

This seems it should be trivially simple but I can't find the time format I would need.

A value comes from the database as 240. This means 240 minutes. How can I store this in a php variable so that php knows it's minutes. So that later in the script I can add it to a `HH:MM` value?

(I have edited the code below to reflect one of the answers)

```
$startTime = new datetime($row['startTime']);  #08:07:00.0000000
$endTime = new datetime($row['endTime']);      #12:10:00.0000000
$everyMinutes = new dateInterval('P'.$row['everyMinutes'].'M'); #60?
$updatedTime = $startTime->add($everyMinutes); # this should read 09:07:00.0000000
```

The date coming into `$row` comes from sql. startTime and endTime are of `time(7)` datatype

```
| taskID |    startTime     |     endTime      | freq |
|________|__________________|__________________|______|
|   1    | 08:07:00.0000000 | 12:10:00.0000000 |  60  |
|   2    | 08:10:00.0000000 | 17:40:00.0000000 |  30  |
|   3    | 08:40:00.0000000 | 14:49:00.0000000 |  60  |
|   4    | 08:43:00.0000000 | 14:49:00.0000000 |  60  |
|   5    | 09:05:00.0000000 | 15:05:00.0000000 |  180 |
|   6    | 10:00:00.0000000 | 22:00:00.0000000 |  5   |
```

With this code I am getting one of two issues. With `new datetime()` the error thrown is `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given'`

Without `new datetime()` the error thrown is `Notice: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

```
$date = new DateTime($row['startTime']);
$myInterval = new DateInterval('P'.$row['everyMinutes'].'M');
$date->add($myInterval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. It did help me debug some of the issues. However now I'm at another roadblock. Any thoughts to the errors above?

Comment: As far as I can see you'e feeding some weird data types into the construct. You should `vardump` $row to check what data is in there since it says `$row['startTime']` is an object instead of a string.

Comment: I could cast those values as something different when I query the db?

Comment: I don't know what kind of object is returned from your DB layer, but with some `strftime` or `date` magic you should be able to convert it easily into something the DateTime constructor accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function convertToHoursMins($time, $format = '%d:%d') {
settype($time, 'integer');
if ($time < 1) {
    return;
}
$hours = floor($time/60);
$minutes = $time%60;
return sprintf($format, $hours, $minutes);
}
```

and pass your time in this like

```
convertToHoursMins(240);
```