# php date less than in date('l, F j') form

Tags: php, date

Here is my exact code:

```
$date = date('l, F j'); 
$start = $row['date']; // equal to Monday, April 15
$interval = $row['interval']; // this is equal to 7 
$end = date('l, F j', strtotime($start ."+$interval days"));

 if ($end < $date) { 
     // do this 
 } else { 
     //yada yada yada
 }
```

I dont know if Im using the variable `$interval` wrong or if the date strtotime +7 days can not be used in this date format.
I would like to keep the date format in this but if I must change then I guess I have to.
The question is Can I use this date format and still add `$interval` amount of days?
When the `$end` date is less than the $date it should do one part of the code and its not doing that part.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If this is your exact code you should be getting a compiler error already on line 1, so I'm not going to attempt to fix this code. Gives us something that basically works and I'll have a go. You should however also read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035604/convert-int-60-to-a-time-value-of-60-minutes/16035652#16035652

Comment: Have you considered creating `DateTime` objects with `createFromFormat()` & using `->add(DateInterval)`?

Comment: Holy syntax errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's your exact code, then `date(l, F j)` on the first line is a syntax error and this code could never ever run as is.

Your problem is that you're converting your time values to STRINGS, and then doing string comparisons.

e.g.

```
('December 1' < 'February 15')
```

is going to be TRUE, because `D` comes before `F`. you need to compare the raw timestamps that strtotime() produces, which are a simple integer:

```
if (strtotime($start) < strtotime($end)) {
   start is less than end
}
```